# Google Chrome 52 JS console is not working on some websites

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

Google chrome browser is not executing JavaScript statements in JS console. 
When I type something,  it does nothing. For some websites its working.
I cannot do some run time JS changes while debugging. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried another browsers debug tool?

Comment: No issues with Firefox. Tried with same URL and steps. It was working till chrome 50.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I believe this is a browser bug.

Comment: Similar issue is reported on [Chromium issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=635866). User there claims that he could not reproduce it on Chrome 53 (currently in beta). If this issue affects you on websites that you have no control over, then running beta channel or downgrading to Chrome 51 seems to be only solutions.

Comment: I'm not facing this issue in chrome Version 53.0.2785.89 m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just having the same problem. I hadn't realised that I had overwritten a built-in object (specifically `Map`), and that was causing the console's strange behaviour exhibited in your screenshot.

Check your code to see if there are any functions/variables being declared in the global scope that have the same name as a built-in object.

Comment: Thanks . We used Identifier name 'Map' to one of custom JS object. I installed chrome 47 and deleted Google update folder from Program files. I sent feedback chrome team but no luck till now. Sometimes open source comes with costs.

Comment: Hi, just to see if there is more of a coincidence, is your Map object for Google Maps API? Also, did my post answer your question? If so, could you press the little green tick, please? :)